# Firefox addon SDK - Sidebar or panel with embedded browser

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I want to develop a firefox addon sdk to show a sidebar or a panel that contains an embedded browser with a navigation bar.

I have constraint too : Since the page shown in the embedded browser, I want to be able to inspect the dom, to hightlight some specific text and also to be able to select text from and send it to a specific input in sidebar with right menu.

Is there some examples or ideas how can I do this?

P.S : I'm sorry for my bad English ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`sidebar`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/ui_sidebar) module, create HTML file with a fixed textarea top:0, left:0, width: 100%. Create an iframe that takes up the rest of the sidebar. User enters text into the textarea, then listen for enter keystroke, use regex to see if it's a URL, and set iframe source to the URL if it's a URL or to a Google search if not.

Loading a whole browser into the sidebar seems like overkill, but if you really want to, try to load chrome://browser/content/browser.xul into the sidebar.

Comment: Update the question with your constraints. Maybe someone will know how to resolve them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This two solutions do the job but I have a constraint and it seems that they don't resolve it. Since the page shown in the embedded browser, I want to be able to inspect the dom, to hightlight some specific text and also to be able to select text from and send it to a specific input in sidebar with right menu. I'm sorry for my bad English ;)